# Which operators in C++ won't be inherited except assignment operator?

Tags: c++, operators

I'm having difficulty understanding this:

It is well known that assignment operator won't be inherited directly... I've asked this yesterday [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867469/do-derived-classes-indirectly-inherit-bases-assignment-operator)

AFAIK following non-virtual operators won't be inherited as well:

```
operator&  //unary user defined
operator* //unary user defined
```

all other operators will be inherited( correct me if I'm wrong )

Which virtual operators won't be inherited? (does virtual specifier make any difference?)

Comment: All member functions are inherited, regardless of whether or not they are operator overloads. `operator=` is special in that it will _always_ be hidden by the derived class implementation whether it is implicitly declared or user declared. I think you may have misunderstood the answer to the linked question if you understood otherwise.

Comment: Note that most binary operators (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%`) should be free functions, not methods, as this will allow conversions that would otherwise not be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking, everything is inherited. However, the following will be *hidden* in the derived class by implicitly-declared versions (or user-declared versions, if the user declares them):

- Default constructor: `T()`
- Destructor: `~T()`
- Copy constructor: `T(T const &)` (sometimes without `const`)
- Copy-assignment operator: `T & operator=(T const &)` (sometimes without `const`)
- Move constructor: `T(T &&)`
- Move-assignment operator: `T & operator=(T &&)`

`operator&` and `operator*` are inherited like everything else. `virtual` declarations make no difference.

Comment: thanks. if I understand:  hidden will ALSO be: assigment operator, move assigment and move copy ctor. is that correct?

Comment: @codekiddy: Yes, I was just adding them when you commented (my C++11 knowledge is a bit sketchy, so I had to look it up to be sure).

Answer (score 4):

The Assignment operator is inherited by the Derived class however the Derived class version of the Assignment operator **[hides](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.9)** the Base class version.

Same is the case with all other operators.

Comment: Well if the rule is so easy then OK :D Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The virtual keyword, when applied to a method, means that subclasses have the option of overriding if they choose to.  If they don't, the superclass behavior is executed when the method is invoked on a subclass.

If the virtual method is pure, then subclasses are required to override it.  There is no default behavior on which they can rely.

Comment: "when the method is invoked on a subclass" -- *via a superclass pointer or reference*.

Answer (score 0):

I have read Book Thinking in C++, in chapter 14 following line is mentioned

Except for the assignment operator, operators are automatically
inherited into a derived class.